# virtualenv use upgraded system default pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

How do I get my virtual environments to use my system upgraded pip?
Before creating a virtualenv, pip shows version 9.0.1, but inside the virtual environment it reverts back to 8.1.1, forcing me to upgrade all my virtualenv pips.

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /tmp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade pip
(venv) $ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /tmp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: should I just add `pip==9.0.1` as the first line of my requirements.txt ?

Comment: I guess you have more than one python installed?

Comment: What does calling `pip3 --version` return when outside the virtual environment?

Comment: I see, `pip3 install -U pip` will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your virtualenv with the command

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Your current Python 3 installation is used as the basis of your virtualenv.

Run the command

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

outside of your virtualenv to upgrade the version of pip you have installed then create a new virtualenv.

Comment: Once the virtual env is activated, I should just use plain `python` and `pip` without the `3` suffixes, right?

Comment: Yes, in your venv/bin/ directory symlinks will have been created for both `python` and `python3`.

Comment: These instructions work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 but not Ubuntu 16.04.  On Ubuntu 16.04, `pip3 --version` outside of the venv shows `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)`.  Then `python3 -m venv venv` shows `pip 8.1.1 from /tmp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`