# I keep getting a message to upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

Whenever I create a venv, I get a message asking me to upgrade pip:

```
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I can upgrade the Pip in that venv fine, after which it is up to date:

```
C:\Users\mkupfer\Python-Sandbox\sibc-python-scripts>pip --version
pip 18.0 from c:\users\mkupfer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\Users\mkupfer\Python-Sandbox\sibc-python-scripts>pip3 --version
pip 18.0 from c:\users\mkupfer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\Users\mkupfer\Python-Sandbox\sibc-python-scripts>pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mkupfer\appdata\local\programs\p
ython\python36-32\lib\site-packages (18.0)
```

but if I create another venv, it will have the same issue. How can I make the upgrade permanent?
I tried the advice at [virtualenv use upgraded system default pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059647), but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Where are you running the command to reinstall `pip`? And where is the message appearing? `pip` may need to be updated in your venv, but you're trying to update in another enviornment

Comment: @Dyno I guess there are two ways to answer that. 1. I ran on windows inside a cmd prompt. 2. Inside the venv after it has been activated.

Comment: This message does not show up when I install outside of a venv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv use upgraded system default pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059647/virtualenv-use-upgraded-system-default-pip)

Comment: I get this message all the time and cannnot upgrade, would be nice to see why and a solution.

Comment: your virtualenv binary is likely belonged to another python installation, use `virtualenv -v venv` to check the detail.

Comment: @Maksim pretty certain that the issue here is that the version of pip packaged with [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) is outdated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue seems to be that *new* virtual environments are using an old version of pip. Note that pip is installed from a source tarfile (or wheel) included with virtualenv, in the `site-packages/virtualenv_support` directory.

```
$ ls -l /path/to/site-packages/virtualenv_support
pip-9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

A quick way to workaround the problem is to make sure you upgrade pip whenever you create a new virtualenv, like so:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ venv/bin/pip install -U pip
```

Alternatively, make sure you have the latest version of virtualenv. According to their [release notes](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/), `virtualenv==16` is using `pip==10`.

```
$ pip install -U virtualenv
```

Finally, since virtualenv looks for `pip*.whl` in `virtualenv_support`, this will also work:

```
$ mv /path/to/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip*.whl{,bak}
$ pip wheel -w /path/to/site-packages/virtualenv_support/ 'pip==18'
```

All new virtualenvs will use the version of pip that you installed into `virtualenv_support`. However, this feels hacky.

(Attempted with `virtualenv==16`. This results in all new virtualenvs with pip==18.)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reply. In regards to the commands you had me run everything points to my 3.6 version of python and doing `pip list` shows that my pip is 18.0. Seems like the `venv` command is using a different version. Is that possible?

Comment: Also: `$ python -m pip install -U pip ` just returns `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mkupfer\appdata\local\programs\p
ython\python36-32\lib\site-packages (18.0)`

Comment: So `virtualenv` was on version `15.1.0`. I updated to `16.0.0` but still having old version of pip. `pip list` shows that I'm still on `pip (9.0.1)`

Comment: Did you create new virtual environment, and verify that the version of pip, in that new virtual environment, is at 9.0.1? Is that is the case, then the release notes for virtualenv are wrong. Also, have you looked inside `virtualenv_support`?

Comment: I did notice that I have a `pipenv 9.0.3`. Does that need to be removed/updated?

Comment: yes I created a new venv --> activated it --> ran `pip list`

Comment: What command are you using to create the virtualenv? Make sure you run `virtualenv --version`, then run `virtualenv venv`. For now, don't use `pipenv`, to simplify the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178643/discussion-between-james-lim-and-maksim).

Comment: Will this ever truly solve the problem? Won't OP just have to redo this step once `virtualenv` is updated or am I missing something?

Comment: If you update `/path/to/site-packages/virtualenv_support/`, all new virtualenvs will use the new pip that you installed there.

Answer (score 6):

For me looks like you have multiple python environments and in one of them, there is not an upgraded pip. You have 2 options:

- navigate to each of that folders and update each pip
- you can remove all of them, reinstall and use virtualenv in future with correct pip
- install some IDE (e.g. PyCharm) that can handle that automatically for you and show all issues visually

Comment: By multiple python environments are you talking about the virtual ones or the python installations themselves?

Comment: Both. Looks like you installed Python to some custom directory. I prefer to install it to a folder like: `C:\Python36\`. So every time I see where all versions are and able to uninstall it. And preferable way is to use mostly python from virtualenv, not root.

Comment: @Maksim, try to uninstall Python completely and install the newest version. After create new virtual environments for your projects.

Comment: that still didn't fix my problem. Unless I didn't uninstall correctly, but that was a bit confusing. I also don't want to use a large IDE, I'm fine with IDLE.

Comment: Had you another version of Python on the same PC? For example 2.7?

Answer (score 3):

Update pip from a bat file:

```
call .\venv\Scripts\activate
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
call deactivate
```

Or if you are in VS Code integrated Terminal

```
& venv/Scripts/activate.ps1
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: This is not the type of solution I'm looking for. I would rather have things working correctly than to create a workaround script.

Comment: @Maksim apologies, I has assumed that you may have been creating a virtualenv from a script, and therefore may have had the luxury of adding a line or two of code.

Comment: I used "pip install --upgrade pip" and it works....

Answer (score 0):

when upgrading pip would uninstall the old version, but if old version is in a different place it cant,hence ending up in two different pip versions. Check your installations on your root PYTHONPATH. 
Also PYTHONPATH may not be same as system path.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to your issue.

**step 1** :
run this command in your shell or jupyter notebook
it will securely download get-pip.py from pypa

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

**step 2** :
run below code

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Situation

In my project folder there was a `venv` with a older version of pyhton inside (trying out stable diffusion).

## Fix

**Deleting this folder** `venv` and re-executing my script worked.

Answer (score -2):

For me I just run:

```
pip install -U virtualenv
```

then my problem solved.

I took this answer from @James-lim
Many thanks to him.

Comment: Please don't repost answers. If an answer was helpful, please upvote the answer.