# -m pip install --upgrade pip, trying to install package "pyaudio'' in visual studio code

Tags: python, pyaudio

[image: error image]

I am trying to install pyaudio but this does not work since it says that pip needs to be upgraded to a new version "19.3"

But when i check it is already updated to the latest version as you can see

[image: version image]

Comment: Try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644402/i-keep-getting-a-message-to-upgrade-pip

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have installed two different versions of python (a `32-bit` version and a `64-bit` version). Your visual studio project is using the `64-bit` version of python and the other one, you are using in command line, is the `32-bit` version. Packages are being installed separately for them.

Comment: okey... did not notice that i need the 32bit only how do i uninstall the 64 bit?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall anything. You can change your projects python interpreter to use the other python installed in your root directory. Go to project preferences of your visual studio project.

Comment: alright now it says ----- Installing 'pyaudio' -----
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
  Found existing installation: PyAudio 0.2.8
----- Failed to install 'pyaudio' -----

Comment: the problem is that it says it has pyaudio installed but when i run it it says no module named "pyaudio"